# why netbeans process same project multi-times at same time?

Tags: java

[Dear all please help me
when I run the project it stills running all over the time 
when I repeat running multi-times I found processor processes more then 10 project s !!!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkYbB.png)

Comment: Please add proper details about the code or the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans allows multiple executions of the same project at the same time. What's probably happening is that app is not shutting down when you close its main window.

The reason: closing a `JFrame` window doesn't necessarily shut down your application.  Unless you say otherwise, the default behavior is to simply **hide** the window and keep the application running.

If you check the **DefaultCloseOperation** property of your app's  `JFrame`, you'll probably find that it's currently set to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.  Change that to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and your application will shut down when the window is closed.

Note that you can still start multiple copies of your application at the same time, if you so desire.  But with the application actually shutting down when you close its window, you're now less likely to find yourself accidentally knee-deep in multiple running copies that you *thought* you had previously killed.

Read all about window-closing options [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-).